# Is it possible to get a z-score greater than 3?

Tags: z-score

I am doing a psychology study with 361 adults 18-62+ years old. I have tested for various variables and got z-scores well beyond 3 such as 9, 14  and the like. I have been told that my data is non-normal. Does that mean my z-scores are correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are your data highly skewed?

Comment: Are the z-scores normalized to their own original variable's sample mean and standard deviation or are they normalized by some external mean and/or standard deviation?

Comment: Exactly how did you get the z score? How have you tested various variables for what question? What are your data/outcome variables (perhaps you are being told that they are non-normal on general principals, e.g. if they are a yes/no question, a time to an event with censoring or the like).

Comment: I have seen something like this at work. The analysis was mis specified in two ways - one way was that the data was a low count so non normal. The other issue was that small sub groups were analysed using the mean and sd of the total population, and as the sub samples were very different, there were some very extreme results.

Answer (score 9):

I will assume that you mean variables that are standardized by their own sample statistics.

Z-values larger than $3$ are certainly possible at $n=361$ for normally distributed data.  Indeed, the largest-magnitude z-score should exceed 3 more than half the time. (If the data were drawn from a non-normal distribution, it can happen as low as $n=11$.)

Here is the distribution of the largest absolute z-score from samples of size 361 from normally-distributed populations (by simulation).

[image]

If you were looking at a single variable, values for the largest magnitude of z-score much past $4$ would be somewhat surprising for samples of this size drawn from a normal distribution. If you're looking at say $20$ variables you would expect some to be bigger than $4$ but you might find a value like say $4.6$ or so somewhat surprising. Values much beyond $5$ are usually not credible for samples of size $361$ from a normal distribution (in the sense that a value at least that large would be an extremely rare occurrence), unless you looked at very large numbers of variables.

---

However, it's not clear why you would care whether any of these variables might be normally distributed (in fact I'd be surprised if any were actually drawn from normal distributions but that shouldn't usually be of any consequence).

Why would it matter if the distribution that some variable was drawn from was a normal distribution?

(What are you doing that would require normal distributions for any of these variables?)

Comment: Under Chebyshev's inequality one data point 14 sd's from mean in sample of 361 is still at the limit, regardless of distribution.  My understanding was that this upper bound usually overstated the chances of such a point considerably. Hence a mis specification or measurement error seems more likely than simply non normal data ( not that there is a particular reason to expect normality)

Comment: @Robert You can get a z-score of almost 19 (18.947) in a sample of size 361 (try 360 0's and one 1). If you use R, you can do that with `n=361; max(abs(scale(c(1,rep(0,n-1)))))`  More generally, you can get a z-score of a tad over $\sqrt{n-2}$ in a sample of size $n$ -- I think the exact bound is $(n-1)/\sqrt{n}$ (which is $\approx \sqrt{n-2}$ for large $n$).

Comment: Your example of how to construct a distribution with such a high z-score seems to underline the point I was trying to make in my last sentence. If the OP was not expecting that kind of extreme data pattern according to their subject matter knowledge, some kind of error or mis-specification seems more plausible than these data accurately reflect what is being studied.

Answer (score 8):

For a data point $x$ and a distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the z-score is just $(x-\mu) / \sigma$. So, a high z-score means the data point is many standard deviations away from the mean. This could happen as a matter of course with [heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution)/[long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail) tailed distributions, or could signify outliers. A good first step would be good to plot a histogram or other density estimator and take a look at the distribution.

Comment: Just to add to your point, assuming the $Z$ is calculated off of sample data, the $\hat{Z}=(x_i-\overline{x})/s$.  A $\hat{Z}$ of 14 would put the point $14s$ away from the mean and a $\hat{Z}$ of 9 would put the point $9s$ away from the mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but just to add another example here to illustrate how this can happen. Lets randomly generate a set of data on IQ scores that is normally distributed but has one extreme outlier: a really, really smart kid:

```
#### Load Libary and Set Random Seed ####
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

#### Create Data ####
data <- tibble(subject = 1:50,
               iq = round(rnorm(n=50,
                          mean=120,
                          sd=15)))

#### Assign Very Smart Subject ####
data[1,2] <- 300
```

Running a density plot of the data:

```
#### Plot Density of Scores ####
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=iq))+
  geom_density(fill = "steelblue",
               alpha = .4)+
  labs(x="Intelligence Quotient",
       y="Density",
       title = "Normal Density vs IQ = 300")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(80,320))
```

You can see that the original normal distribution still exists but the person with 300 IQ is very much an outlier now:

[image]

To figure out just how much of an outlier, we can create a variable called `z_score` which gets the number of standard deviations above/below the mean for each subject and then filter for those equal to or above 3 SD:

```
#### Create Z Scores ####
data %>% 
  mutate(z_score = (iq-mean(iq))/sd(iq)) %>% 
  filter(z_score >= 3)
```

We can see this person has a crazy z-score...its 6 standard deviations above the mean:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  subject    iq z_score
    <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
1       1   300    6.09
```

We can visualize just how extreme by plotting the same data but now with 3 standard deviations above and below the mean marked with red dashed lines:

```
#### Plot Z Score Limits ####
data %>% 
  mutate(z_score = (iq-mean(iq))/sd(iq),
         sd = sd(iq),
         mean = mean(iq)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=iq))+
  geom_density(fill = "steelblue",
               alpha = .4)+
  labs(x="Intelligence Quotient",
       y="Density",
       title = "Normal Density vs IQ = 300")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean+(3*sd)),
             color="red",
             linetype="dashed")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean-(3*sd)),
             color="red",
             linetype="dashed")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,320))
```

And here you can see that the smart kid is far above the metric we set:

[image]